# Programming a 3D model from 2D images with CUDA

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I'm wondering if anyone has done a project like this. I am thinking of making this for my undergraduate thesis. So basically, I want to take a set of 2D MRI photos and program a 3D model of some sort, using CUDA and C. However, I can't seem to find any good examples, and the best source for the images I was able to find was [this](http://brainweb.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/brainweb/). Has anyone had any experience with these kind of programming, and if so could you provide me with a link, I would like to see what it looks like. Also, am I looking in the right way when I think of using CUDA here? Is there perhaps some other way?

Comment: @wendelbsilva Yes, Volume Rendering is probably the path to go. I can't open the demo, since webgl is crashing but I think it might be close to what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to improve my comment and put it as an answer.

Looks like you are looking for algorithms like IsoSurface or a Volume Rendering.

In both algorithms, you receive a volume (for example, a set of 2D MRI photos) and do the visualization over it.

You can see an example of a volume rendering [here](http://demos.vicomtech.org/volren/).
This example is using this set of images [here](http://demos.vicomtech.org/volren/aorta-low.jpg).

Nowadays is straight forward to implement a Volume Rendering using shaders, so you dont need to do it on CUDA.
For IsoSurface, last time I checked CUDA had an example of an IsoSurface algorithm on it (they implement the algorithm marching cubes).

Comment: I opened it now, yes that is close, but I wanted to make it a little bit more "active", so to say. And I would like to make it a bit sharper, but as I said very close.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by sharper, but you can change the transfer function used on the Volume Render at your will (like [here](http://www.crowdlabs.org/datasets/view3d/10/)).

Comment: interesting... I've never done something like this before, so it will take some time to learn. :)

Comment: Ray-casting volume rendering is not hard to implement on GPU after you learn what each step does (not hard to implement, maybe hard to debug when its the first time implementing). Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~trier/?page_id=98).